# How to use the fully qualified name of a method?

Tags: c#, powershell, linq

I need an embedded C# code snippet for my Powershell script like this:

```
$myArray = @(7,6,5,4)

Add-Type @"
public static int[] indexOfMin(int[] arr){
    int min = arr.Linq.Min();
    return new int[] {min, Array.IndexOf(arr, min)};
}
"@ -name my -Namespace System

$minValue, $minIndex = [my]::indexOfMin($myArray)
```

I am looking for a simple way to specify the Min()-method from Linq without having the additional lines for the using-block and the class-wrapper.

Is there any simple way to specify the assembly of that single call of Min()?

Comment: If this code is not merely an example, do note that this code loops through the array twice, when getting both the minimum and its index could be done in one pass -- without even requiring LINQ. Or C#, for that matter.

Comment: As an aside: It's better to pass a _custom_ namespace rather than `System` to the `-Namespace` parameter, so as to avoid potential conflicts with built-in types.
If you don't pass a `-Namespace` argument at all, the output type, as specified via the `-Name` parameter, is placed in the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes` namespace, 
requiring use of the full type name to access it, e.g. `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.my]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-UsingNamespace` parameter to include a namespace reference to `System.Linq` so the compiler can resolve the `.Min()` extension method:

```
$myArray = @(7,6,5,4)

Add-Type @"
public static int[] indexOfMin(int[] arr){
    int min = arr.Min();
    return new int[] {min, Array.IndexOf(arr, min)};
}
"@ -name my -Namespace System -UsingNamespace System.Linq

$minValue, $minIndex = [my]::indexOfMin($myArray)
```